# Для чего нужен Eager в связке с Lazy?

Tags: java, hibernate

Был на собеседовании и задали такой вопрос:

> У нас есть Eager and Lazy, почему всегда не пользоваться Lazy? Для чего нужен Eager? Ведь если Eager initialization потребляет больше памяти, из-за чего это может сказаться на производительности..

Comment: Бывают случаи, когда вы часто приходиться использовать коллекцию/элемент, поэтому чтобы не создавать дополнительное квери -> ставится eager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть несколько случаев когда *ранняя загрузка* более предпочтительна:

1. Иногда нам проще загрузить все данные сразу и работать с ними, нежели держать соединение до тех пор пока нам потребуется очередная порция данных
2. Это может позволить так же сократить количество запросов - например, вместо двух один с join'ом. Порой это оказывается быстрее

Comment: Спасибо большое, за ответ)